# How to edit a text file through command prompt in a windows container?

Tags: docker, containers, command-line-arguments, command-prompt, windows-server

I am struggling on this issue for a while now. Can anyone help me to edit a text file through command prompt in a windows container?
I should be able to read the file in command prompt and edit it as well within a Windows container.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the struggle - What have you tried? What didn't work? Anyway, this doesn't really seem to be about programming, so it may be off-topic for SO.

Comment: `edit filename.txt` didn't work out. With `more filename.txt` I am able to read the information but cant edit it.